Clock at top of screen displaying odd values instead of time in Ubuntu 23.10
Settings > Date & Time show correct options, but the clock on the top of the screen displays numbers (time of 24:40) that don't make any sense (although the date is correct). See screenshot 


Nothing happens.

@user68186 correct. I fixed the issue by resetting all Gnome-shell extensions. I am hoping it doesn't recur

Don't forget to accept your own answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to your answer and turn it green. This will help others.

Here's how I fixed it. This will reset all custom Gnome extensions but will save the settings for possible restoration later.
Using the terminal:
mv ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions_OLD 
mkdir ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
gnome-session-quit --no-prompt

The issue was resolved after logging back in.
